# Does Copperhorn Scout untap land creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have an [Ambush Commander](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAmbush%20Commander%5d) out which makes each forest that I control a 1/1 green Elf creature that's still a land.

If I have four tapped Forests and I attack with [Copperhorn Scout](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCopperhorn%20Scout%5d), does this cause the land creatures to untap (since they are creatures), or would they stay tapped (since they are lands)?

Answer (score 9):

They are creatures, therefore they untap. If the ability doesn't specify that it applies only to nonland creatures, then it applies to all creatures, regardless of other types they might have.